# I want to display API data on first load in React

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I can see that the data is being console logged but in my return statement it doesn't render and the data is null. I am well aware that before I get the data the page is being rendered first. How can I make it render after it has received the data?

```
  const [bookingData, setBookingData] = useState(null);

  const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/test/api'

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
    console.log(bookingData)
  }, []);

  function fetchData() {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => { 
      console.log(response.data.data[0])
      setBookingData(response.data.data[0])
  });
  }

  return (
    <div> {bookingData.tracking_id} </div>
  );
```

Comment: I don't see a return statement?

Comment: return is just a <div> {bookingData.tracking_id} </div> It has no data. It is null.

Comment: Moreover, I do a simple <div> Hello </div> and then replace hello with this {bookingData.tracking_id} it shows the data on the browser but when I hit refresh with the browser it is null which means I need to get the data on first load.

Comment: Here its making api call and api will take some time to fetch data so it wont show the data on first render. Maybe at that time you can show Loader (loading state).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I was able to make it work by adding a loading state.

Answer (score 0):

Since fetching data from an API is an asyncronous function, you'll have to use an async function.

```js
  async function fetchData () {
    axios.get(url).then((response) => { 
      console.log(response.data.data[0])
      setBookingData(response.data.data[0])
  });
  }
```

Comment: sorry my bad, its async function fetchData(), noit function fetchData async()